# Measurable functions on complete space.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

$(\Omega, \mathcal{E}, \mathbb{P})$ a probability space,  $\mathcal{F}$ is $\mathcal{E}$ completed by the $\mathbb{P}-$null sets. Which conditions should meet a topological space $X$ (taken with its Borel $\sigma$ algebra) so that for any map $f$ from $\Omega$ to $X$ conditions (1) and (2) below are equivalent ?

(1) $f$ is $\mathcal{F}-$measurable

(2) There exists a $\mathcal{E}-$measurable $g$ (from $\Omega$ to $X$) so that $f=g$ holds everywhere, or only fails on some null set

In particular does it work for any separable normed vector space ? I don't find the proof when $X$ is not Hilbert. Any classical reference is welcome. Thank you.